# Dojo Grid to html or report

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

Is there a way to get the results from a Dojo Grid to a report or PDF?  Cant really find any info on that.  Maybe convert the records in the Dojo Grid into HTML and then to a report?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing right now.  Just need to figure out a way to get the results of the grid into html or some sort of report (PDF maybe)

HTML

id="gridNoColumnSets_impediments" class="gridclassGrid"

```
    gridNoColumnSets_impediments = new (declare([Grid, Selection, ColumnSet]))({
       // use Infinity so that all data is available in the grid
       bufferRows: Infinity,
       cellNavigation: false,
       escapeHTMLInData: false,
       showHeader: true,
       noDataMessage: "No results for this search",
       loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
       selectionMode: "single",
    }, "gridNoColumnSets_impediments");

    gridNoColumnSets_impediments.on(".field-id:mouseover", selectStateimpediments);

    var ColumnSets_impediments = [
        [
            [
                {label: 'id', field: 'id', sortable: false},
                {label: 'ID__', field: 'ID__'},
                {label: 'IMPEDIMENT', field: 'IMPEDIMENT'},
                {label: 'OTHER_NAME', field: 'OTHER_NAME'},
                {label: 'RIVER', field: 'RIVER'},
                {label: 'COUNTY', field: 'COUNTY'},
                {label: 'HU_NAME', field: 'HU_NAME'},
                {label: 'DAM_TYPE', field: 'DAM_TYPE'},
                {label: 'OWNER', field: 'OWNER'},
                {label: 'STATE_AGCY', field: 'STATE_AGCY'},
                {label: 'FED_AGCY', field: 'FED_AGCY'}
            ]
        ],
    ];

    gridNoColumnSets_impediments.set("columnSets", ColumnSets_impediments);




  function updateGridimpediments(featureSet) {
    var data = arrayUtils.map(featureSet.features, function (entry, i) {
      return {
        ID__: entry.attributes.ID__,
        id: entry.attributes.OBJECTID,
        IMPEDIMENT: entry.attributes.IMPEDIMENT,
        OTHER_NAME: entry.attributes.OTHER_NAME,
        RIVER: entry.attributes.RIVER,
        COUNTY: entry.attributes.COUNTY,
        HU_NAME: entry.attributes.HU_NAME,
        DAM_TYPE: entry.attributes.DAM_TYPE,
        OWNER: entry.attributes.OWNER,
        STATE_AGCY: entry.attributes.STATE_AGCY,
        FED_AGCY: entry.attributes.FED_AGCY
      };
    });

    // If you use a store...
    dataStore = new Memory({
        "data": data,
        "idProperty": "id"
    });

    gridNoColumnSets_impediments.set("store", dataStore);
    gridNoColumnSets_impediments.startup();

  }
```